# Can't add function to Option element

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am getting some data from an API in which i need to get a dog breed, and create a card which display some info on it. I am at the beginning and I am stuck.

```
//Area where data will be displayed
var showcase = document.getElementById('showcase');

var select = document.getElementById('select-bar');

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Get data from API endpoint
request.open('GET', 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list', true);

request.onload = function () {
   var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
   var breeds = data.message;

   if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400 ) {
     for (var i = 0; i < breeds.length; i++) {

       var opt = document.createElement('option');
       opt.innerHTML = breeds[i];
       opt.value = breeds[i];
       opt.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('Hey !')})
       select.appendChild(opt);

    }
   }
  }

request.send();
```

With the click event, it is not the final one that I am doing, but the point that I am trying to get across is that absolutely no function I've put there works. I've tried this with every other element , and this is the only element that doesn't work. Help? :(

Comment: So, you want to alert when you change an option from that dropdown you are creating?

Comment: you should add the `event` in the `select` not in the `option`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add event listener to the `select` node with `onchange` event and not for each option node.

[**onchange**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

```
select.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  alert("HELLO");
})
```

```js
var showcase = document.getElementById('showcase');

var select = document.getElementById('select-bar');

select.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  alert("HELLO");
})

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Get data from API endpoint
request.open('GET', 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list', true);

request.onload = function () {
   var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
   var breeds = data.message;

   if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400 ) {
     for (var i = 0; i < breeds.length; i++) {

       var opt = document.createElement('option');
       opt.innerHTML = breeds[i];
       opt.value = breeds[i];
       select.appendChild(opt);

    }
   }
  }

request.send();
```

```html
<div id="showcase">
  <select id="select-bar">
  </select>
</div>
```